# Python regular expressions

Tags: python

Is there any regular expression to match this:

- a continuous string of characters or/and digits XOR
- a string of any characters between a pairquotation marks (" XOR ')including nested quotations

?

Examples:

- dgsdggsgggdggsggsd
- 'dsfsasf .asgafaasfafw rq'
- "sadas fa fasfa "

Comment: what is the `or/and` ... `XOR`?   can you enclose the syntax in parentheses?  is the `XOR` on the first line to be `XOR`ed with the second line?

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail about the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to either match a string between quotation marks (either " or ') or a string of alphanumeric characters between spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
>>> message = "blabla df qdsf dqsf \"fqdfdqsfsdf  fdqs fqdsf\""
>>> pattern = "(\w+|'.*[^']'|\".*[^\"]\")"
>>> re.findall(pattern, message)
['blabla', 'df', 'qdsf', 'dqsf', '"fqdfdqsfsdf  fdqs fqdsf"']
```

Comment: it doesn't actually behave as you said. the last quotation mark is omitted from the result. also I would like no to get the quotation in the result. ex "safasfaf" becomes safasfaf

Comment: doesn't matter, got it working, changed the pattern to (\w+|'.*[^']'|\".*[^\"]\")

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps relevant: do you know about the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module?